# A Very Special Crossword

Tags: wordplay, crosswords

While sorting through things after a move, I came across my first ever crossword made without use  of a computer. It was just me, sitting at my family table with a piece of paper and a dictionary. After I found it, I spent the rest of the day (rather than unpacking more boxes as I should've been) making some creative crossword clues for the grid! I hope you all enjoy this puzzle as 9-year old me put a lot of effort into this grid.

[image: croword]

Text Version:

```
_ _ _ ■ _ ■ _ _ _ ■ _ ■ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ ■ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ ■ _ ■ _ ■ _ ■ _ ■ _ _ _
■ _ ■ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ■ _ ■
_ _ _ _ ■ _ ■ _ ■ _ ■ _ _ _ _
■ _ ■ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ■ _ ■
_ _ _ _ ■ _ ■ _ ■ _ ■ _ _ _ _
_ ■ ■ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ■ ■ _
_ _ _ _ ■ _ ■ _ ■ _ ■ _ _ _ _
■ _ ■ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ■ _ ■
_ _ _ _ ■ _ ■ _ ■ _ ■ _ _ _ _
■ _ ■ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ ■ _ ■
_ _ _ ■ _ ■ _ ■ _ ■ _ ■ _ _ _
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ ■ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
_ _ _ ■ _ ■ _ _ _ ■ _ ■ _ _ _

ACROSS
1.  Feminine pronoun (3)
5.  Perfected speed run (1.1.1)
8.  Epoch (3)
11. Competition (7)
12. Bargainer (7)
13. Anger (3)
14. Welcome rug (3)
15. Else (9)
20. Taunt (4)
21. Blood-related (4)
22. Give ways (9)
23. At this location (4)
24. Makes it? (4)
26. Measure (4)
27. Part of murder? (4)
28. Creep (4)
31. Try-hard coolness (4)
33. Mature films (9)
34. Cake level (4)
35. Up to then (4)
36. Waterlogs (9)
41. Vegetable or crude? (3)
43. Sanctuary (3)
45. Wandering (7)
[Error 404: Clue not found]
47. Finish (3)
48. Consume (3)
49. Rude donkey (3)

DOWN
1.  ___ Lanka, country (3)
2.  Furry (7)
3.  Adam’s partner (3)
4.  Not sharp (4)
5.  Sort (4)
6.  Above-ground potato (4)
7.  Becomes older (4)
8.  Nightmarish street? (3)
9.  British city (7)
10. Banana on a wall, maybe? (3) 
15. Viewers (9)
16. Highlight (9)
17. Cord (4)
18. Revolutionary (9)
19. Longitudinal axes (9)
23. Fortune (3)
25. Atmosphere (3)
29. Issue (7)
30. Celestial celebrity? (4)
32. Public execution (7)
37. Singular 19? (4)
38. Advise (4)
39. Neighbour (4)
40. Scares (4)
41. Mineral (3)
42. Young boy (3)
43. Organisms (3)
```

Comment: Just a note- that's not CSV version, it's just a code block version (code blocks are also pretty inaccessible to screen readers, by the way, especially for the clues as they should be read like regular text). CSVs by definition need to be lists separated by commas (Comma Separated Values)

Comment: I have all but 3 of your clues (I think) - just 5A and 6D to go (5A doesn't even make sense to me - is it a gaming thing?), but does 16D actually clue a word other than itself?

Comment: Oh dear, I seem to have made a mistake with 16D somewhere along the puzzle-making phase... The answer is indeed itself, thanks for noticing that. 6D is a rather obscure term but I think both remaining clues are within the realm of solvability. Good job on getting so far, I can't wait to see your finished answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filled grid:

> [image: filled 15×15 grid]

Clues:

> [image: list of clues with explanations]

A short comment on the clues:

> Some of the clues don't match in part of speech (which I assume is an artifact of the puzzle being made by a nine-year-old). But there are some clever clues, too - I particularly liked 24A, which misled me nicely into the "creates some unknown object" parsing.

Comment: You are extremely close to getting all of the crossword correct, yet two of your answers are incorrect. I can assure you that this is actually a crossword grid I made when I was 9 years old, and not a hidden puzzle. I just thought since I found it it would be nice to resurface it! (also 24A was my favorite clue as well)

Comment: Hm, alright then. I'm guessing 20A is one of them, and the other might be 37D? But I'm not sure of anything better for either of those.

Comment: I hope you don't mind me asking, but what program/website did you use for creating the images in this solution? I've seen this crossword solution grid in other places on Puzzling but I don't know what the program is...

Comment: After my remarks in chat, yes my workings differ to yours in just 2 places - these may help: rot13(V guvax 20N vf DHVO naq 37Q vf whfg NKVF.)

Comment: @TakingNotes I just used Google Sheets! The grid was made by shading in cells, and just left of each column of clues was a left-aligned column that I filled answers into. (Also, I see what's going on with 37d now that Stiv's shared his answers... not sure how I missed that.)

Comment: @Deusovi Oh, haha! I'm imagining a Google Sheet with tonnes of crossword solutions on it now...